Using a comma to format a list of independent clauses

CEOs are overpaid; their payment exceeds their performance, they purposely use their influence to pass plans with larger-than-deserved payment plans, and the compensation of CEOs rewards them even when they are underperforming relative to their peers

I wrote this sentence, and my teacher marked it as a comma splice, but I always assumed that you could use a comma to organize lists. I checked it using grammarly and chatgpt. They both gave clean bills of report, so who is wrong?

Try using a colon instead of a semi-colon. Then, you have three parallel statements about CEOs.

In addition to starting with a colon, you could replace your commas with semicolons.  I think most style guides recommend this when the items in the list contains commas themselves, but in this case it would remove any possibility of interpretation as a comma splice.

Lambie identifies that there are not four list points here, but an elaboration of three listed sub-points adding details after a statement of the whole situation. Lists may comtain commas whether they are lists of NPs, or suitable clauses (including independent clauses). The supercomma usage of the semicolon is not required here, but the list is properly introduced by a colon or dash, as stated. And the listing comma after 'plans' is virtually mandatory in this case.

@DougWarren I guess I'll edit to address it, but it should be clarified that using commas in a series in no way creates comma splice.

A series of independent clauses is not a "list".

There’s no problem here, but I would reword the last item, as a matter of style: ..., and their compensation rewards them even when they are underperforming relative to their peers

I've voted to close since it's a matter of opinion how something should be punctuated.  There are intelligent and reasonable ways to punctuate the sentence in the question which might be rejected by some style sheets and accepted by others.

An answer with a reference:

Observe that you can connect three or more complete sentences with
listing commas, as in the Lisa/Juliet example [1] below. Note the
difference here:
[1] Lisa speaks French, Juliet speaks Italian[,] and I speak Spanish.
[2] *Lisa speaks French, Juliet speaks Italian.
Remember, you must not join two complete sentences with a comma, but
three or more complete sentences may be joined with listing commas
plus and or or.

[Larry Trask, University of Sussex, 1997]
I hesitate to give this, though, as Trask goes on to recommend the avoidance of the serial (Oxford) comma in 'BrE', and IMO (and that of many) is far too prescriptive in 'you must not join two complete sentences with a comma'. There are good balanced answers on ELU giving far better recommendations (the Oxford comma can sometimes disambiguate but sometimes add ambiguity, and there are 'comma splice' examples where it would be petty to object).

Eat, drink, and be merry.

No, this is not comma splice. Comma splice is when you use a comma to join two independent clauses, like "CEOs are overpaid, they make too much." A common way to fix it is to turn the comma into a semicolon. If your first semicolon had been a comma instead, you would have comma splice. Meanwhile, the commas that are actually contained in your sentence are unrelated. Yes, we use commas in a series.* If you deleted "CEOs are overpaid," you would still have a valid sentence.
The best action now is to ask your teacher for clarification, preferably giving them a chance to save face if they don't properly understand comma splice. We can only guess at why they marked it as such, but some possibilities are:

They hastily mistook the semicolon for a comma
They are unclear on the definition of comma splice and simply feel that the sentence is too long and complicated and want a rewording. (Another term for comma splice is "run-on sentence," leading to the common misperception that it applies to "any sentence that is longer than I like.")
They're not aware that the semicolon makes it valid.

By the way, I would discourage reliance on AI tools to be sure of whether you're using language the right way. Use them as a safety net to catch mistakes as you want, but double-check their findings by doing your own quick learning about suggested problems, or by asking teachers (perhaps not this one!).

* As some have mentioned, if the elements in a series become very complicated themselves, with internal commas, it might be nice to replace these commas with parentheses. This doesn't really change the way the grammar operates, though. And personally, I feel that when one reaches that point it's time to reword into shorter sentences anyway.

I've never used it myself, but my impression is that Grammarly is more likely to give false alarms than erroneous clean bills.

Not for nothing, but the items in the list do happen to all be independent clauses.

+1 "their payment exceeds their performance, they purposely use their influence to pass plans" certainly looks like a comma-splice given a hasty inspection. Is your argument it is not because there are 3 and not 2 independent clauses metered out as comma-delimitted list?

@JD A simpler sentence with the same structure might be: "Bob is weird; his hair is always untidy, he rides a unicycle, and his house is painted purple." Yes, there are ways to create comma splice out of a list (e.g., if the "and" weren't present before the final item). But anyone wearing such restrictive blinders that they can only see two clauses at a time maybe doesn't have any business saying what's going on in the overall sentence.

I upvoted; I worry, however, that restrictive blinders are the rule rather than the exception on complex grammatical matters. ; ) Thanks for the feedback.

@JD Oh and I just realized on re-reading that the "restrictive blinders" comment could be taken as directed at you, but no, I was thinking of the teacher grading the paper. That is, it would have to be such a hasty inspection that such a person has no business marking usage errors.

@AndyBonner I didn't take it directed at me. I'm a pedant, so even such an accusation would be baseless. ; ) I have met a fair amount of primary and secondary English teachers, and found the decision to drop grammatical rigor from the elementary and secondary curriculum to be a political decision to be inclusive more than a desire to uphold sensible educational standards. I'm no friend to prescriptivism, but at a certain point thwarting reasonable convention in communication is counterproductive to the interests of equity.

(1) Is it deliberate that you use comma splice as a non-count noun? It sounds odd to me. // (2) Replacing commas with parentheses in lists? How would that work? Using semicolons instead of commas is common, but I don’t think I’ve ever seen a list that uses parentheses instead of commas.

You text:

CEOs are overpaid; their payment exceeds their performance, they purposely use their influence to pass plans with larger-than-deserved payment plans, and the compensation of CEOs rewards them even when they are underperforming relative to their peers

The first two independent clauses "payment exceeds" and "they... use" are definitely at first glance apparently a comma splice. This is certainly a stylistic concern, and I suspect there's one style guide out there (probably the AP) that signs off on this sort of construction, but historically, the use of semicolons are frequently used when building a list out of three independent clauses. So a more acceptable revision is more likely:

CEOs are overpaid: their payment exceeds their performance; they purposely use their influence to pass plans with larger-than-deserved payment plans; and the compensation of CEOs rewards them even when they are underperforming relative to their peers.

In this way, the original colon demarcates the translation to an immediately related set of sentences, the semicolons then keep the list "pscyhologically and conceptually" close, and one can use commas freely for comma-delimited lists in phrases such as noun or verb phrases without making the list of independent clauses difficult to parse.
Remember that these sort of questions of grammar prescriptions are best answered by looking to the language community in question, and therefore most language communities who take syntax serious appeal to a style guide. My preferences are The Chicago Manual of Style, but there are other famous ones too and they might disagree over particulars (see the Oxford comma). Steven Pinker, a noted psycholinguist has his own take given his expertise in cognitive science and the philosophy of language and presents his ideas in The Sense of Style, which might be worth a read

I would temper the opening bit about semicolons a bit. Chicago recommends semicolons in a complex series: "when items in a series themselves contain internal punctuation, separating the items with semicolons can aid clarity. If ambiguity seems unlikely, commas may be used instead." They're certainly not needed for all series.

How can you possibly call this "a comma splice"?

@tchrist Is this a trick question? By misapprehension, a point I delineated with a tad of explicature in the form of 'apparently'. How else do you explain the OP's teacher's rationale? If you're under the impression I characterized it as a comma splice, you'd best reread with an eye for the intricacies.

@AndyBonner I'm confused. Is a series of three independent thoughts subordinate to the semantics of a fourth thought demarcated by colon not a complex series? If not, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions in your estimation?

You have some typos. "the use of semicolons are frequently used", "pscyhologically", and "syntax serious".

@JD No, that is not a complex series – and it wouldn’t matter if it were, because the deciding factor in whether you should ‘upgrade’ to semicolons is how complex the items in the series are. If one or more of the individual clauses in the series contains its own punctuation, especially commas, then that punctuation clashes with the commas delimiting each item in the series, and it makes sense to use semicolons for the latter purpose. If there is no punctuation inside any of the items (as here), then commas will usually do just fine.

Also, “definitely at first glance apparently a comma splice” does not indicate that calling it a comma splice is a misapprehension. It sets up an expectation that a counter-argument will be presented to show that it is a comma splice only in appearance and not in reality, but no such argument ever comes, so the reader is left to conclude that you are indeed calling it a comma splice.

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. I'll review when I get a chance.

"The teacher to whom the janitor gifted the box of chocolates that were from the expensive online store walked into the room, the room which had been the teacher's for use in the instruction over a number of decades was a warm reminder of the sense of community, and the community from which the janitor came owed a debt to both the janitor and the teacher because they had established a camaraderie given their mutual conscientious work ethic and their strong concern for the success of their students." @JanusBahsJacquet None of the independent clauses require anything more than a full stop...

and linking them together is ungainly with commas, is utterly ungainly. In a constituent grammar, there are more dimensions of complexity than is additional punctation being used. But I don't even have to provide this counter example to your proposed rule, because the OP's teacher was obviously confused by the use of commas, which while one can attack the abilities of the teacher, given the length of the sentences, it's simply a case of poking a bear...

As for the other setting up arguments it's not a comma splice, I simply left that to the dictionary. The main idea of this answer however, has nothing to do with comma splices at all, but rather is an advisement that different language communities have different standards. A student in a classroom simply has a right to ask an instructor whose grammatical biases they are expected to honor. I"m not here to argue about comma splices, but simply make manifest language prescription isn't anything more than opinion, yours included

But I do appreciate the conviction of your opinion, if that hasn't been made clear. I'm always appreciative of push back! :D

That example is indeed quite ungainly. But it would be with semicolons as well, because (1) it’s not really a list consisting of three sentences, but three sentences with an internal relationship to each other (the second and third both depend on the first in their back-references); and (2) all three sentences are cumbersome, unnatural and poorly written to begin with. As for the rule of items containing punctuation, it’s not my rule, but the one laid out in style guides like the CMoS – discretion should of course be applied.

My point was that “a series of three independent thoughts subordinate to the semantics of a fourth thought demarcated by colon” is not a construction that automatically requires a semicolon. The example in the question doesn’t, for example, nor does the following: “I had several reasons for going to the park: it was a nice day, I was bored, and my dog needed exercise”. Using a semicolon there would make it feel like you’re trying to be Jane Austen.
